# How to get integers to an array (from integer i to integer j). c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, integer, store

I want to store integers(in an array or anything) that in range of int "i" and int "j".

eg:-Think, "int i = 1" and "int j = 10".I want to store integers from 1 and 10.
So that (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Because I want to answer to HackerRank "Beautiful Days at the Movies".
link below.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-days-at-the-movies/problem?isFullScreen=false

here is my code and it a garbage.

```
static int beautifulDays(int i, int j, int k) {

var total = 0;

for(var a = i; a <= j; a++ )
{ 
  if (a != 0)
 {
    int ri = Reverse(i);
    int rj = Reverse(j);
    var ra = Reverse(a);

    if((ra/k) % 1 == 0)
    {
       total++;
    }

    if((rj/k) % 1 == 0)
    {
       total++;
    }   

    if((ri/k) % 1 == 0)
    {
        total++;
    }
} 
return total;

}
return total;

}
public static int Reverse(int inval)
{
    int result = 0;

    do
    {
        result = (result * 10) + (inval % 10);
        inval = inval / 10;

    }
    while(inval > 0);

    return result;
}
```

simply, can you give me the answer of HackerRank "Beautiful Days at the Movies".
link below.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-days-at-the-movies/problem?isFullScreen=false

Comment: Please put your actual question in your post, and also add the code that you've written, and explain what bit you're having trouble with. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service: people aren't going to read a set of requirements from another website, and write you up a solution

Comment: Your question is too vague, dear. Please ask clearer questions so that people are encouraged to answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Using Java you can easily stream a range of numbers with IntStream, then map the reverse function for each value, then filter those that fulfils the condition and count. With streams you don't need to store, you can get straight to the answer.

```
IntUnaryOperator reverse = (opperand) -> {
        int reversed = 0;
        int num = opperand;
        while (num != 0) {
            int digit = num % 10;
            reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;
            num /= 10;
        }
        return Math.abs(opperand - reversed);
    };

    return (int) IntStream.rangeClosed(i, j).map(reverse)
            .filter(v -> v % k == 0).count();
```